# Weird JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, coding-style

Can someone explain to me why undefined is being printed only in firefox for document.write on the last line.  When the first document.write is removed however it works great, and it seems to be like this only in Firefox.

```
document.write("Hello <br />");
myVar = 55;
document.write(window.myVar);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/43pbj/1/

Comment: It works fine if you remove `window.`, so why can't you just do that?

Comment: Because the variable should be accessible through the window object.  It is on every other browser.

Comment: Well, not all browsers agree with that unless you define it as that as MBJ said.

Comment: The bug is that if you comment out the first line in FF, then it will work, but that only applies for Firefox.  The code above from what I can tell is valid and legal code.

Comment: Proper usage of jsFiddle matters too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of jsfiddle. You have the script wrapped in an anonymous function that's bound to the page's onload event with mootools's `addEvent()` function. For some reason running the code in an onload event causes the scope not be `window` in Firefox.

If you look at the page source the code looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.addEvent('load', function() {
document.write("Hello <br />");
myVar = 55;
document.write(window.myVar);

});//]]> 
</script>
```

If you run the same script without any libraries and not in any event it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/43pbj/4/

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `myVar` from the `window` object, but not setting it as such.

Do either:

```
window.myVar = 55;
document.write(window.myVar);
```

or:

```
var myVar = 55;
document.write(myVar);
```

**EDIT:**

Just as a note, I would go with the second option unless you absolutely need the variable attached to the `window` object.

Comment: `var myVar = 55;` if defined in global namespace, it attaches to the global `window` by default.

Comment: @PranavKapoor well the issue is resolved when you define it with `window.myVar`, so apparently that isn't entirely true for all browsers - whether it be intentional or just a bug.

Comment: @DylanCross : Variable Declaration at [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Declaring_variables)

Comment: @PranavKapoor Sure it may say that, but you can't deny that redefining it as so doesn't for some reason fix the issue... because it does, so it's clear that that is the issue...